# AngularJS data binding in controller and template operating on different scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried many tips from numerous other answers but can't seem to find anything that works nor that is specific to my situation.

When the document is scrolled, it is processed by my controller but the value changing doesn't reflect in the template data bindings. However, clicking a toggle test link in the template does work and I can't figure out how to fix this.

Controller:

```
.controller('pageNav', ['$interval', '$document', function($interval, $document) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.pub = {};
  vm.pub.isPinned = 0;
  vm.togglePin = togglePin;
  vm.topBuffer = 100;

  vm.pub.isPinned = ($document.scrollTop() >= vm.topBuffer) ? 1 : 0;

  $document.on('scroll', function() {

    var dtop = $document.scrollTop();

    if (dtop >= vm.topBuffer && vm.pub.isPinned == 0) {
      vm.togglePin();
    } else if (dtop < vm.topBuffer && vm.pub.isPinned == 1) {
      vm.togglePin();
    }
  });

  function togglePin() {
    vm.pub.isPinned = (vm.pub.isPinned == 1) ? 0 : 1;
  }
}])
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="pageNav as pNav">
   <div class="subHead stripe" ng-class="{pinnedPageNav: pNav.pub.isPinned}">
      <a href="">Home</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/jehqvvtg/4/

I thought maybe it would work here without extra code but it is the exact same behavior I'm seeing on my site.

--

This problem is also affecting another controller where data is loaded via a service (no problems here) but doesn't show in template. This exact controller worked on a site I coded a couple months ago and it still works fine there but suddenly I drop it in here it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to update your scope like so:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    vm.pub.isPinned = (vm.pub.isPinned == 1) ? 0 : 1;
})
```

I have updated your fiddle as well:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jehqvvtg/5/)

Comment: Ok this works and I'm guessing it's because of this bit: $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).